# NoSuchMethodError com.google.android.gms.internal.g.f

Tags: android, google-play, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a difficult problem to solve. I've published my app on Play and everything is okay, but the problem is that there are 2 devices that crashes the app with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.IOException.<init>
at com.google.android.gms.internal.g.f(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.g.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.bq.ac(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.cg$1.run(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ch$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

I just know this error because Play shows me, but it's impossible to see where it is. Besides, I have another information. Here is the thing: It happens when the user chooses to see the map in a drawer menu and the error is in the first time he chooses.

Here is the code of this fragment:

```
package br.ufc.ondefica.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import br.ufc.ondefica.MainActivity;
import br.ufc.ondefica.R;
import br.ufc.ondefica.model.Placemark;
import br.ufc.ondefica.utils.DataHelper;
import br.ufc.ondefica.utils.ParserKML;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class UFCMapFragment extends FragmentWithSearch {
    private GoogleMap map;
    private int positionToShow = 3;
    private boolean isDefaultView = true;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container, false);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTitle(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sliding_menu)[0]);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("positionToShow")) {
            isDefaultView = false;
            positionToShow = bundle.getInt("positionToShow");
        }
        loadMap();
        // Move the camera instantly to the default place to show with a zoom of
        // 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(DataHelper.data.places
                .get(positionToShow).getCoordinates(), 13));
        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16), 4000, null);
    }

    private void loadMap() {
        for (int i = 0; i < DataHelper.data.places.size(); i++) {
            Placemark place = DataHelper.data.places.get(i);
            Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(ParserKML
                            .loadMapOfIcons(place.getIconID())))
                    .title(place.getName()).snippet(place.getDescription())
                    .position(place.getCoordinates()));
            if (i == positionToShow && !isDefaultView)
                marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

The devices that crashes are: Samsung Galaxy ACE (GT-S5830B) and Samsung Galaxy 5 (GT-I5500B). Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first line on the stracktrace give you a clue:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.IOException.<init>
```

Basically it's saying that some constructor for `IOException` is missing. Looking at the [javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/IOException.html), there are two constructors that were added in API level 9:

```
public IOException (Throwable cause)
public IOException (String message, Throwable cause)
```

That should answer your question. API level 9 is Android 2.3. Hence, the stack trace is from a device running Android 2.2 or below, which is missing the two constructors above.

There are at least two solutions to solve the problem:

- Change the `minSdkVersion` in your app's manifest to `9`.
- Don't use the latest Google Play Services library, but use the Froyo version in stead.

The latter you can find in the SDK Manager. It was added with the [last update](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html) because support for Froyo (Android 2.2) was dropped. Quote from the linked blog post:

> With over 97% of devices now running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) or
>   newer platform versions, we’re dropping support for Froyo from this
>   release of the Google Play services SDK in order to make it possible
>   to offer more powerful APIs in the future. That means you will not be
>   able to utilize these new APIs on devices running Android 2.2 (Froyo).

Comment: I realized about the IOException some days before, but I didn't find out how to solve it and now everything makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: I get this exact exception on versions 2.3.x which are Gingerbread, when using the new Google Play Services.

Comment: What other implications are there? That is, the version name of the latest google-play-services-lib is 4.0.30, but the Froyo's version is at 3.2.65. Is this gonna affect negatively non-Froyo (~97% of them) users?

Comment: There is a third solution: guard the code that requires new functionality in Google Play Services (such as Admob ads) with a `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)`