# Exceptions from com.google.android.gms,internal after switching to new admob google ads

Tags: android, exception, admob, google-play-services

I get the following exceptions on google play from my app (after deobfuscation):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.IOException.<init>
at com.google.android.gms.internal.et.e(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.et.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.dx.void co()(Unknown Source)
                                      void b(long)
                                      com.google.android.gms.internal.ee a(com.google.android.gms.internal.dx)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.dx.void co()(Unknown Source)
                                      void b(long)
                                      com.google.android.gms.internal.ee a(com.google.android.gms.internal.dx)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.fm$a$a.com.google.android.gms.internal.fk b(com.google.android.gms.internal.fi)(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.an.void aV()(Unknown Source)
                                      com.google.android.gms.internal.an$a a(android.view.View,com.google.android.gms.internal.ak)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.br$a.run(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.bs$a.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

and

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.gms.internal.fm$a$a.com.google.android.gms.internal.fk b(com.google.android.gms.internal.fi)(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.an.void aV()(Unknown Source)
                                      com.google.android.gms.internal.an$a a(android.view.View,com.google.android.gms.internal.ak)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.br$a.run(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.bs$a.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I am using admob and had zero crashes, but since the latest admob requirement to switch to google play services for ads I have tones of crashes. I am using the proguard properly so the problem is not with the obfuscation. Before diving in the google code hope someone already did some research and knows where I should look at. Did not expect this from google and still hope this is something I've missed so I could fix it and continue using admob.

**EDIT**
I am using the banner and the interstitial the following way:

```
private void prepareAdBanner() {
    try {
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

      mAdView = new AdView(this);
      mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
      mAdView.setAdUnitId(ADMOB_BANNER_ID);
      mAdView.setLayoutParams(params);

      ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.banner_layout);
      layout.addView(mAdView);

      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
          //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
          //.addTestDevice(DeviceInfo.getInstance().getDeviceId())
          .build();

      mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }catch (Exception e){
      LLog.e("Failed to load banner", e);
    }
```

and

```
private void prepareInterstitial() {
    try {
      mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
      mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_ID);
      mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
          super.onAdClosed();
          goToMainActivity();
        }
      });

      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
          //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
          //.addTestDevice(DeviceInfo.getInstance().getDeviceId())
          .build();

      mInterstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    }catch (Exception e){
      LLog.e("Failed to load interstisial", e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's not possible to help you unless you paste relevant part of your code regarding AdMob (declaration, initialization, etc).

Comment: also please deobfuscate the stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry guys, pasted the deobfuscated code and added the preparation of the banner and interstitial.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think I found the solution to my problem. Will double check it and update the answer or remove the question.

At least one exception can be explained here:
[NoSuchMethodError com.google.android.gms.internal.g.f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081385/nosuchmethoderror-com-google-android-gms-internal-g-f)

My minimum SDK was 2.2 for some time while using the google play services that do not support this version. I did not use the Froyo google play version for the old API.